# Last array number keeps going wrong after switch statment

Tags: c

For example if i enter: `"123456-7"`. The output at the first print statement would be: `"123456-7"` and at the 2nd print statement it would be `"7"`. Which is correct.

But at any point after the break if I print the array again the print statement would go wrong in the last digit. It would look like: `"123456-1"` and the second would look like `"1"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lotoNumbers[6];
    int ticketNumbers[6];
    char option;

    while(option != 'C')
    {    
        printf("Your option:");
        scanf(" %c", &option);

        switch(option)
        {
            case 'W': printf("Please enter todays winning ticket number:");
                      scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d-%1d", &lotoNumbers[0], &lotoNumbers[1], &lotoNumbers[2], &lotoNumbers[3], &lotoNumbers[4], &lotoNumbers[5], &lotoNumbers[6]);

                      printf("Your loto ticket number is: %d%d%d%d%d%d-%d\n", lotoNumbers[0], lotoNumbers[1], lotoNumbers[2], lotoNumbers[3], lotoNumbers[4], lotoNumbers[5], lotoNumbers[6]);
                      printf("----The following numbers matched! %d\n", lotoNumbers[6]);
                      break;

            case 'T': printf("Please enter your ticket number:");  
                      scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d-%1d", &ticketNumbers[0],&ticketNumbers[1],&ticketNumbers[2],&ticketNumbers[3],&ticketNumbers[4],&ticketNumbers[5],&ticketNumbers[6]);

                      printf("Your loto ticket number is: %d%d%d%d%d%d-%d\n", ticketNumbers[0], ticketNumbers[1], ticketNumbers[2], ticketNumbers[3], ticketNumbers[4], ticketNumbers[5], ticketNumbers[6]);
                      break;

            case 'C': printf("Computing....\n");
                      break;

            case 'Q': printf("The program will now quit. Thank you for playing LOTO 649.\n");
                      return (0);
                      break;

            default: printf("You entered an invalid option. The program will now terminate.\n");
                     return (0);
        }
    }

    printf("The numbers are:%d%d%d%d%d%d-%d\n", lotoNumbers[0], lotoNumbers[1], lotoNumbers[2], lotoNumbers[3], lotoNumbers[4], lotoNumbers[5], lotoNumbers[6]);
    printf("The number is: %d\n", lotoNumbers[6]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: we need an example code that can be compiled. get rid of all the unrelevant stuff.

Comment: Good idea to check the result of `scanf()` _before_ using `lotoNumbers`.   Insure it is 7.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94807/auto-ban-questions-that-use-pastebin

Comment: Noted will do in the future. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is the fourth question you've asked that boils down incorrect use of array indices.  You'll save a lot of time if you read through some online tutorials about arrays and indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't allocate enough space for your arrays.  The number used to allocate space for an array is the number of entries in the array, not the last index number.  Index 6 is the 7th item and is past the end of the array.  The value of lotoNumbers[6] is undefined and can change randomly, because the program is using that memory for something else.

```
int lotoNumbers[6];
int ticketNumbers[6];
```

That 6 should be 7.